# Mysterious PNG RGB+Alpha image that works with IE6

Tags: image, image-processing, internet-explorer-6, png

http://moztw.org/images/product-front-thunderbird.png

I am sure that this is a PNG image in RGB colors and a alpha channel (look at the shadow below the icon), but this file mysteriously works with IE6 w/o any special CSS hack (though it seems the alpha channel is being replaced by 2-bit mask in IE6).

Can anyone tell me exactly what information is in the file? It would be even better if someone could give a guidance on how to create such file. Thanks.

**Edit:** Friends at moztw.org added script hack to the website, so the above statement is no longer verifiable. But your are still welcome to investigate the image format.

Comment: I believe the secret is not in the .png image itself but in the page somehow. I know there were workarounds for showing png transparency in IE6 but I'm not familiar with the specifics.

Comment: http://moztw.org/ http://moztw.org/dl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's PNG8+alpha. [Explanation and examples in "PNG that works" article](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/png-that-works/#8bit+alpha).

You can generate such files with [pngquant](http://pornel.net/pngquant) (on a Mac, [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com) is a GUI for it).